# image smoothing in c

Tags: c, arrays, image, 2d, smoothing

Alright so I'm trying to have a user input the number of columns and rows and then have the output bring up a random number matrix followed by a smoothed image matrix that finds the mean filter for every pixel in the array. Right now I have it to where it can give me a random number matrix, but the smoothed matrix is all out of whack. Right now the code I have written is just focusing on integers that have 4 neighbors, but clearly I have done something wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
// function that randomly generates numbers 
void fillArray(int a[10][20], int m, int n)
{
  int random;
  int i,j;   
      for (i=0;i<m;i++)
      {
          for (j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
                           random=rand()%100;
                           a[i][j]=random;
                           }
                           }
  }
  // function that prints the first matrix of random numbers
  void printarray (int a[10][20], int m, int n)
 {
 int i,j;
for (i=0;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
                     printf("%4d", a[i][j]);
                     }
                     printf("\n");
                     }
  }
  // function that finds the mean for any number and its 4 nieghbors 
  void smooth (int a[10][20], int m, int n)
 {

 int i,j;
 for (i=1;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        a[i][j]=a[i][j]=(a[i-1][j]+a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j]+a[i][j+1])/4;
        printf("%4d",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
 }
 }
 int main()
{

int a[10][20];
 int m,n;
 srand(time(NULL));
 //User input
 printf("please enter number of columns and rows");
 scanf("%d %d", &m,&n);
 fillArray(a,m,n);
 printarray (a,m,n);
 printf("The smoothed image is\n");
 smooth(a,m,n);
 getch();
return 0;
}
```

right now if I entered 3 and 3 I would get something like this:

```
23 43 54
12 76 89
56 98 24

The smoothed image is
347373849493234343
12 23345345345
2132334565645645645
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I am surprised that your program does not encounter error when you smooth for corners and margins; those should be special casses, treated differently.

Comment: @coraldoe, I've fixed most of the program, my only issue now is I can't seem to fix the boundary issues for the right hand margin and 2 right hand corners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you access a[m][..] and a[..][n] (since you loop while i < m for example, and access i+1) which were not initialized in your random numbers generating function.

edit: when you assign values, each loop goes from 0 to m-1 / n-1

```
for (i=0;i<m;i++)
      {
          for (j=0;j<n;j++)
          {
                           random=rand()%100;
                           a[i][j]=random;
                           }
                           }
```

however when you use these values, each loop goes from 1 to m-1/n-1, but inside this loop you use the neighbor cells (i-1, j-1, i+1, j+1)

```
 for (i=1;i<m;i++) 
{
    for (j=1;j<n;j++)
    {
        a[i][j]=(a[i-1][j]+a[i][j-1]+a[i+1][j]+a[i][j+1])/4;
        }
 }
 }
```

this means that on the last iteration (i = m - 1), you access cells which were not initialized, because you access i+1 = m
keep in mind that multi dimensional array is actually a 1-dimensional array in memory, so some of these calls are not really to uninitialized values, but some are

to fix this you can loop until m/n (and not m-1/n-1) in your assignment stage

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what you're saying, could you point out what you mean within the code from above?

Comment: Alright, I have the program working for the most part, but I may have gone about it a little weird. I can now return the values for the top left hand corner number, the left side of numbers, and the middle set of numbers, but I can only do them individually. Is there a way to combine the 3 sets into one matrix( eventually I will need to combine the 9 sets) or did I go about this completely wrong?